# This code outputs the Chinese Characters that's inside code properly, while outputs the Chinese Characters catched from Scanner as junk

Tags: java

I am trying to catch the Chinese Characters from Scanner.

I am running in cmd.exe on Windows 10.

I've already run CHCP 65001.

[image]

here is the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaScannerCN
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("中文 user name: ");
    String username = scanner.next();
    scanner.close();
    System.out.println(String.format("Hello, %s", username));
    System.out.println((int)'中');
    System.out.println((int)username.charAt(0));
  }
}
```

thanks to @ParkerHalo reminder, it seems the character received has been damaged, since the output is

```
Hello, ��
20013
96
```

This code outputs the Chinese Characters that's inside code properly, while outputs the Chinese Characters catched from Scanner as junk.

How to fix that?

Comment: is your console UTF-8?

Comment: `chcp 65001` on Windows, it what @Cwrwhaf possibly wants you to do.

Comment: Print the numerical value of the character `System.out.println((int)'中');` and then the character you get from the scanner: `System.out.println((int)username.charAt(0));`. Maybe that difference can help you in your research

Comment: @Cwrwhaf I've run `CHCP 65001` in cmd.exe, although I am not sure whether it changed to UTF-8.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thanks for your comments. I've updated the post. I did run `chcp 65001`, which seems not work.

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405428/can-i-get-console-to-show-chinese

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could cause this problem. One of them that charset in your windows environment. I would suggest a diagnostic tool that may help you to diagnose your problem and in turn, will lead you to an appropriate solution. There is an Open Source java library MgntUtils that has a Utility that converts Strings to unicode sequence and vise versa:

```
result = "Hello World";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The output of this code is:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064
Hello World
```

The library can be found at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.2/jar) or at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) It comes as maven artifact and with sources and JavaDoc. Here is JavaDoc for the class [StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html).

I suggest that you convert your input string that you receive from a scanner into Unicode sequences, and it will help you to understand if you received already damaged info or your problem is a display problem.

Comment: Thanks for your approach! It seems what I received has already been damaged, how to fix that?

Comment: I found this question that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using

Comment: try to run command "chcp 65001" on your console before you run your program. That will switch it to UTF-8 charset and that should resolve your issue